# If checkbox is checked, then select one radio

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox "CR". If it is checked it opens up a div which contains 2 radio buttons("IA" and "FA"). Now, if the user checks "CR" but does not select at least one radio, it should throw an alert that "At least one must be selected."
In my case, The alert pops up even if one of the radio button is checked. I am guessing I am missing on something very minute but couldn't figure out.
Below is the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_cr" id="CR"/>CR
<input type="radio" id="IA" name="Initial" />IA
<input type="radio" id="FA" name="Final" />FA
<input type="submit" />

<script>
else if(this.CR.checked) 
                 {
                     if((!this.IA.checked) || (!this.FA.checked))
                 {
                     alert("Choose the approver type");
                     return false;
                 }
                 }
</script>
```

PS: "Else if" because, I am doing a couple of other validations too.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to provide the complete validation code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your or (`||`) should be an and (`&&`).

Right now, if either is unchecked, the alert pops up.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that both the radio buttons must be selected?

Comment: No it means that both must be unchecked.

Comment: Ohh yes!! Got it! Thank You so much. Knew that was making some very silly mistake but couldn't figure that out.

Comment: Yep. The `or` would belong there if neither of the `this.xx.checked` had been negated with the `!` operators, and instead the whole expression would be. `if (!(this.FA.checked || this.IA.checked))`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making that boolean more readable by doing the following:

```
var bothUnchecked = ( !this.IA.checked && !this.FA.checked )

if( bothUnchecked ) {
    ...
}
```